# Gatsby: Using SASS module with Typescript

Tags: typescript, sass, gatsby, css-modules

I am trying to make typescript and sass module work together on a Gatsby project.

I am using `gatsby-plugin-ts-loader` and `gatsby-plugin-sass` plugins.

**index.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './index.module.scss'; // TS2307: Cannot find module './index.module.scss'.

export default () => <div  className={styles.root}>
    <h1>Hello Gatsby!</h1>
</div>;
```

**index.module.scss**

```
.root {
  h1 {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

I get the following error `TS2307: Cannot find module './index.module.scss'.`.
If I put `@ts-ignore` before the scss import line I get `TypeError: index_module_scss_1.default is undefined`.

Answer (score 9):

1. Add `"esModuleInterop": true` to `tsconfig.json`.
2. Add a file `src/global.d.ts` with content:

```js
// necessary to make scss module work. See https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/8144#issuecomment-438206866
declare module '*.scss' {
    const content: {[className: string]: string};
    export = content;
}
```

3. Add import `import styles from './index.module.scss';`
4. If it compile, and css does not show, make sure it is correct, like confusing `.root` and `root` ;).

Source https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/8144#issuecomment-438206866